# Count If A and B matches, then numbers in sequence before A changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, select, count

I have a puzzling question for SQL.

I'm looking to take 2 single criteria (criteria1 and criteria2), test it against a single row criteria in a database, then if they both match, to get a COUNT on rows in a sequence before criteria1 changes.

We have a shared table of consecutive 'serial' type numbers but with different 'part' type numbers and are looking to get a count of rows of consecutive numbers if the first test matches.

Like:

```
AA  12
AA  13
AA  14
AA  15
BB  16 
BB  17
BB  18
AA  19
AA  20
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE column1 WHEN 'criteria1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    FROM [dbo].[tableName] 
    WHERE [column1] = 'criteria1' AND [column2] BETWEEN criteria2 AND criteria3
```

And:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tableName]  WHERE 
[column1] = 'criteria1' AND [column2] = criteria2)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(CASE column1 WHEN 'criteria1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
    FROM [dbo].[tableName] 
    WHERE [column1] = 'criteria1' AND [column2] BETWEEN criteria2 AND criteria3
END
```

These don't do an initial criteria1 matches and criteria2 matches test before getting the series count, but get the count for matches overall 'between' criteria2 and criteria3, tho not without (consecutive) fault.  These also don't look at consecutive matches before criteria1 would change.  This can be done via stored procedure or direct statement.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide an example of the output you want.

Comment: This is a SQL database, and I'd be quite content with just getting an initial check in with the end result being the count of rows that include the initial match before the 'criteria1' changes.

Comment: Something like: process count where initial test of col1 is 'AA' and col2 is '13' then of how many 'AA' are across the criteria2 to criteria3 value...with the end result being the count of rows that include the initial match before the 'criteria1' then changes.  For example, using the above AA table, the return value would be 2 if the query was WHERE 'AA' is from '14'.  The result would be 2 because 'AA' changes to 'BB'.  Another example would be result 3 WHERE 'BB' is from '16' as it then changes to 'AA'.

Comment: Quick update: I ended up loading the range of data into a datatable in code behind to then process for the match.  I was hoping to do this in t-sql, but couldn't find or think of a good solution as above.